# Open file upload dialog after Ajax post success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have functionality in which it is required to open file upload dialog after Ajax call success event.

**What I tried:**
I tried applying below simple code in ajax **success:** and **complete:** event but it is not working.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: eoid },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            // some logic
            $("#fileupload").click();
        }
    });
```

**What is problem:**
If I put simple button and try to execute above code, it is *working fine* and opening dialog - but it is *not working in case of ajax post afterwards*.

Any guesses or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: show the relevant code?

Comment: Yep, there it is..

Comment: You are defining ajax to be `GET` and trying to send data?

Comment: No, I am calling ajax and getting html in return to display in div element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at `dataType: 'json'` . You are loading html with your ajax request so you should change it to `dataType: 'html'` else in any other format it will not be considered success. Or you can delete this property as stated in [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) doc that Jquery does `default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the update - I tried applying that code but no luck.. It is loading html correctly, but that file upload dialog is not prompting.

Comment: You are talking about `$("#fileupload").click();` not working? Is this in ajax loaded html?

Comment: Yes, HTML is coming from ajax request and in success - above click is not opening dialog.

Comment: Try navigating from document `$(document).find("#fileupload").click();`

Comment: I will be able to help if there is any kind  fiddle sample. Anyway you can also debug to see where the problem is. Like `console.log(data)` inside success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120960/discussion-between-k-s-and-the-eht).